# log4j jsp import

Tags: java, jsp, log4j

I'm getting the following, yet log4j works fine in the java files of a Java EE project

```
09:09:56,785 ERROR [0]] Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=404, location=/pages/sorry3.jsp]
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type org.apache.log4j.Logger cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

An error occurred at line: 10 in the generated java file
The import org.apache.log4j.Logger cannot be resolved

An error occurred at line: 54 in the jsp file: /pages/sorry3.jsp
Logger cannot be resolved

53:     
54:     Logger.getLogger("com.mysite.myapp.jsps.sorry3").error(
55:         "Page Not Found: " + pageContext.getErrorData().getRequestURI());
56: %>
57:
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Comment: the import is at the top of the page too: <%@page import="org.apache.log4j.Logger"%>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you don’t have the log4.jar / log4j.properties in your classpath at all.

Add it in your CLASSPATH.

Generally, log4j.properties should be at `WEB-INF/classes`.

It should work

Comment: what is the location of log4j.properties in your project

Comment: I am using geronimo, and it comes packaged. I have sucessfully used it and have it logging the way I want. To answer your question, Its in {geronimo_home}/var/log/server-log4j.properties

Comment: Put your server-log4j.properties in WEB-INF/classes then try. It should work